# How to Add animated pin on map in android?

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-animation

I just cant add animated pin on map. For clarification see app like (Maps app,Glypse app) i have added a snap

[image]

see the circled arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got the solution..i used animation for that here it is which might help to someone

This is my fadein.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<alpha
    android:duration="900"
    android:fromAlpha="0.2"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

which i applied on image(pin) and invoke animation from java file like this..

```
        imgv.setImageResource(R.drawable.pinred);

        Animation myanim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(DealsActivity.this,
                R.anim.fadein);
        imgv.startAnimation(myanim);

MapView.LayoutParams lp = new MapView.LayoutParams(
                MapView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                MapView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Currentgp,
                MapView.LayoutParams.BOTTOM_CENTER);

        mv.addView(imgv, lp);
```

where..
     imgv is object of ImageView and mv is of Mapview

Comment: if you guys have any query regarding this feel free to ask

Comment: @zen have not tried with maps api V2 yet...i have implemented this around a year ago